# Django + Heroku: Do automatic migrations need an advisory lock?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am currently setting up my project via Heroku. 
I got stuck [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#design-considerations) where it says:

> The following considerations are primarily relevant when creating
>   manual database migration scripts. If you are using an ORM, such as
>   ActiveRecord, these considerations may not apply.

My question is, do I have to do this when I use Django's command in the RUN command `python manage.py migrate`?

> Before running a migration, grab an advisory lock on the database

Or is this the ORM case and I don't have to 'grab' this advisory lock. Thank you!